# NSHelpManager/AHGotoPage failure in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, apple-help

I try to open a help book within a system preference pane using `AHRegisterHelpBook` and `AHGotoPage`.  It works under OS 10.9, but fails under 10.12.

```
OSStatus err = AHGotoPage( CFSTR("AutoPairs Help"), NULL, NULL );
```

Specifically, the calls return noErr, but the first time I call `AHGotoPage`, the help window opens with a message saying that the help could not be found.  Subsequent calls to `AHGotoPage` seem to do nothing at all.  Is there some other way to open an embedded help book?

Update: Somehow I had overlooked the existence of the Cocoa class `NSHelpManager`.  After updating my help book index with anchors and converting to use of the `NSHelpManager` methods `registerBooksInBundle:` and `openHelpAnchor:inBook:`, I am still in the situation where it works in Mavericks and fails in Sierra.

[image: Sierra help fail message]

Comment: i am also facing this issue, you got any solution for this do share with us.